# unable to start terracota

Tags: centos, ehcache, digital-ocean, terracotta

I'm having issue when starting terracota, I did grep on `37.139.24.150` ip in whole system but couldn't find any file containing this IP, any other places to look for? Also i couldn't find tc-config.xml in terracota its actually an old system I'm just starting terracota its not installed/configured by me.

```
2015-03-12 13:02:09,737 [main] INFO com.terracottatech.dso - Statistics store: '/root/terracotta/server-statistics'.
2015-03-12 13:02:09,750 [main] INFO com.terracottatech.console - Available Max Runtime Memory: 490MB
2015-03-12 13:02:09,958 [main] INFO com.terracottatech.dso - Standard DSO Server created
2015-03-12 13:02:09,962 [main] INFO com.terracottatech.dso - Creating server nodeID: NodeID[37.139.24.150:9510]
2015-03-12 13:02:09,973 [main] ERROR com.terracottatech.console - Unable to find local network interface for 37.139.24.150
2015-03-12 13:02:09,975 [main] ERROR com.terracottatech.dso - Unable to find local network interface for 37.139.24.150
com.tc.exception.TCRuntimeException: Unable to find local network interface for 37.139.24.150
        at com.tc.objectserver.impl.DistributedObjectServer.start(DistributedObjectServer.java:502)
        at com.tc.server.TCServerImpl.startDSOServer(TCServerImpl.java:531)
        at com.tc.server.TCServerImpl.access$600(TCServerImpl.java:92)
        at com.tc.server.TCServerImpl$StartAction.execute(TCServerImpl.java:479)
        at com.tc.lang.StartupHelper.startUp(StartupHelper.java:39)
        at com.tc.server.TCServerImpl.startServer(TCServerImpl.java:510)
        at com.tc.server.TCServerImpl.start(TCServerImpl.java:271)
        at com.tc.server.TCServerMain.main(TCServerMain.java:30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work, I've created new tc-config.xml and started server with `./start-tc-server.sh -f /home/tomcat/terracotta/latest/terracotta/bin/tc-config.xml &`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- All content copyright Terracotta, Inc., unless otherwise indicated. All rights reserved. -->
<tc:tc-config xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.terracotta.org/schema/terracotta-5.xsd" 
xmlns:tc="http://www.terracotta.org/config" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <servers>
    <!-- Sets where the Terracotta server can be found. Replace the value of host with the server's IP address. -->
    <server host="<my-server-ip>" name="localhost">
      <data>/home/tomcat/terracotta/server-data</data>
      <logs>/home/tomcat/terracotta/server-logs</logs>
      <statistics>/home/tomcat/terracotta/server-statistics</statistics>
    </server>

<!-- If using more than one server, add an <ha> section. -->
    <ha>
      <mode>networked-active-passive</mode>
      <networked-active-passive>
        <election-time>5</election-time>
      </networked-active-passive>
    </ha>
  </servers>
  <!-- Sets where the generated client logs are saved on clients. Note that the exact location of Terracotta logs on client machines may vary based on the value of user.home and the local disk layout. -->  
  <clients>
    <logs>/opt/terracotta/client-logs</logs>
  </clients>
</tc:tc-config>
```